# How to get the port number of client request with AWS ELB using TCP and Nginx on server

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elb

While using HTTP/HTTPS as load balancer protocol we get the requested origin protocol (i.e. it is HTTP or HTTPS) from `x-forwarded-protocol` header. 
Now, using this header in nginx configuration it can be determined that whether the originating call was from HTTP or HTTPS and action could be performed accordingly.

But if the ELB listeners configuration is as shown in the below image, then how to determine that the request has come via port 80 or port 443?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of options, at least:

Option 1 is not to send both types of traffic to the same port on the instances.  Instead, configure the application to listen on an additional port, such as 81 or 8080, and send the SSL-originating traffic there.  Then use the port where the traffic arrives at the instance, to differentiate between the two types of traffic.

Option 2 is to enable the `PROXY` protocol on the ELB, after modifying the application to understand it. This has the advantage of also giving you the client IP address.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/enable-proxy-protocol.html

http://www.haproxy.org/download/1.5/doc/proxy-protocol.txt

Comment: Thanks man, the first simple solution worked and we couldn't use the second option as nginx doesn't fully support proxy protocol(only gives source IP).

Comment: @michael-sqlbot How do you get the info about port from the proxy protocol in nginx? I can only get the client's ip...